# c++ put vector to struct without copy

Tags: c++, vector, visual-studio-2008, struct, cuda

How to put vector to struct in c++ (msvc 2008).

For example...

I have headers file .hh:

```
template <typename dtype> struct c_Cudamat_Struct1 {
    thrust::device_vector<dtype> deviceVector;
    dtype * dataHost;
    dtype * dataDevice;
    int onDevice;
    int onHost;
    (void *) shape;
    int size;
    int isTrans; // 0 or 1
    int ownsData;
    int itemsize;

};

template <typename dtype> int thrust_copy_to_device(c_Cudamat_Struct1<dtype> * mat);
template int thrust_copy_to_device<double>(c_Cudamat_Struct1<double> * mat);
template int thrust_copy_to_device<float>(c_Cudamat_Struct1<float> * mat);
template int thrust_copy_to_device<long>(c_Cudamat_Struct1<long> * mat);
template int thrust_copy_to_device<int>(c_Cudamat_Struct1<int> * mat);
template int thrust_copy_to_device<char>(c_Cudamat_Struct1<char> * mat);
```

And I have some main (?) .cu file:

```
template <typename dtype> int thrust_copy_to_device(c_Cudamat_Struct1<dtype> * mat){

    print_memory_gpu("1. Start:::");

    thrust::device_vector<dtype> deviceVector(mat->dataHost, mat->dataHost + mat->size);

    print_memory_gpu("2. Create deviceVector:::");

    mat->deviceVector = deviceVector;

    print_memory_gpu("3. Put deviceVector to mat:::");


    mat->deviceVector=thrust_vector_fill_range<dtype>(mat->deviceVector, 1, mat->size);

    print_memory_gpu("4. mat->deviceVector linspace:::");


    return 0;
}
```

But its making copy:

> 1. Start::: Free/Total GPU memory (MB): 1541/-2048
> 2. Create deviceVector::: Free/Total GPU memory (MB): 1160/-2048
> 3. Put deviceVector to mat::: Free/Total GPU memory (MB): 778/-2048
> 4. mat->deviceVector linspace::: Free/Total GPU memory (MB): 876/-2048

**EDIT 000/999**

Highlighting whats important (others I will handle with pointers from "`mat->dataDevice`")...

```
template <typename dtype> int thrust_copy_to_device(c_Cudamat_Struct1<dtype> * mat){

    print_memory_gpu("1. Start:::");

    thrust::device_vector<dtype> deviceVector(mat->dataHost, mat->dataHost + mat->size);

    print_memory_gpu("2. Create deviceVector:::");

    mat->deviceVector = deviceVector;

    print_memory_gpu("3. Put deviceVector to mat:::");


    return 0;
}
```

How could i change this part:

```
thrust::device_vector<dtype> deviceVector(mat->dataHost, mat->dataHost + mat->size);

print_memory_gpu("2. Create deviceVector:::");

mat->deviceVector = deviceVector;
```

To something like:

```
thrust::device_vector<dtype> mat->deviceVector(mat->dataHost, mat->dataHost + mat->size);

print_memory_gpu("2. Create deviceVector:::");
```

**EDIT 001/999**

The problem is that pointers are OK, but I still need this vector and make it available from struct.

Should I create class in place of this struct with some crafty methods?

**EDIT 002/999**

Simplest solution seems to be creation of class instead of struct:

In header .hh file:

```
template <class dtype> class C_Cudamat_Struct{
    private:
        thrust::device_vector<dtype> deviceVector;
    public:
        C_Cudamat_Struct();
        dtype * dataHost;
        dtype * dataDevice;
        int onDevice;
        int onHost;
        (void *) shape;
        int size;
        int isTrans; // 0 or 1
        int ownsData;
        int itemsize;

        int set_device_vector();

};

template class C_Cudamat_Struct<double>;
template class C_Cudamat_Struct<float>;
template class C_Cudamat_Struct<long>;
template class C_Cudamat_Struct<int>;
```

In main (?) .cu file:

```
template <class dtype> int C_Cudamat_Struct<dtype>::set_device_vector(){
    print_memory_gpu("1. Start:::");

    thrust::device_vector<dtype> deviceVector(dataHost, dataHost + size);

    print_memory_gpu("2. Create deviceVector:::");

    //mat->deviceVector = std::move (deviceVector);

    print_memory_gpu("3. Put deviceVector to mat:::");

    deviceVector=thrust_vector_fill_range<dtype>(deviceVector, 1, size);

    print_memory_gpu("4. mat->deviceVector linspace:::");

    return 0;

}

template <class dtype> C_Cudamat_Struct<dtype>::C_Cudamat_Struct(){

}
```

Comment: Without seeing the source code of thrust::device_vector it is hard to tell, but possibly you can replace copy operations by moves: `mat->deviceVector = std::move (deviceVector);`

Comment: @H. Guijt - It would be nice, bit this gives me error: namespace "std" has no member "move"

Comment: It's in <utility> You could, however, have attempted to google it for yourself.

Comment: I thought its in std...

Comment: I don't know what to say. Do you really not know the difference between an include file and a namespace?

Comment: I started fun in c++ like few days ago, maybe even whole week. Before when I had to move from python to c++, and when I saw this, I said "blah, hell no, lets go cython". But c++ seems unavoidable for now. So im totally noob in c++. In python is all plain and soft, c++ is.. heh U know.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I was thrown by your use of advanced features (templates, GPUs, neither of which are beginner level). Most beginners here are struggling to reimplement std::vector or std::list badly; your code suggests a significantly higher level of understanding. You should `#include <utility>` to get access to std::move. If you do there is however a chance your vector type might not implement move semantics to begin with. If it is under your control you can change that, otherwise you will need to look for a different solution.

Comment: Heh... Im drinking a lot of juice so my cpu is not overheating... extremly. Finally c++ seems to not very hard, somehow not caussing infinite recursion in my brain. Maybe like reading some "mechanical engineering book", but volume of knowledge that I could eat is limited so usually Im struggling with noobish mistakes. I need c++ to wrap python with cuda/opengl - thats why im asking theese advanced things. C++ is rly simmilar with python, like working with granite and cement, its same work.. Btw is this move function available in C++ msvc 2008 or from c++11? #include <utility> not made it work.

Comment: It's a C++11 thing. The notion that instead of copying everything in sight, you could also just move them around and save yourself the trouble of making endless copies, is really what separates C++11 from the earlier versions.

Comment: Python 2.7 from anaconda forces to use msvc 2008 so I have to stick with it :<. Some #@!@#$ are downwoting me :< so I have to delete this question... Wait till I dominate Ur all downwoters $@#% HeHe... U will se whos downwoting who then :P

Comment: @RobertGrzelka: I downvoted this. And I did so because you have taken what was a fairly poor question ("Why do I get a copy when I use copy assignment") and have now edited to the point where is it unreadable and completely useless to anyone. A question isn't your personal plaything and they exist to help everyone, not just you. And I am not here to help you. I am here to answer your question. There is an important difference between the two.

Comment: @RobertGrzelka: As you have probably now realized, [SO] has [serial voting detection](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) and your downvotes on some of my answers were automatically reversed. My suggestion is that you spend more time and energy working on the quality of your questions and less on acting like a child.

Comment: HeHe I know it so its rly nice; no harm to anyone thought its free beach slap... Its hard to ask question with proper formulation. If I could properly formulate my question, I can easily answer it on my own. Hardest thing is that some questions popup from lack of knowledge and then it is like "What the hell I am asking for?... Its black magic, lets put code as my question...".

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: the C++ compiler will not do it for you, you have to do it yourself. If you don't want to make a copy, store a `std::shared_ptr`, or perhaps `std::unique_ptr` to the vector, in your struct.

Alternatively, construct the `struct` first, use `reserve()` to reserve the expected number of elements in the `struct`'s vector, then populate the `struct`'s vector directly. You cannot construct a vector as a separate object first, then copy it somewhere without, well, actually making a copy.

Looks like you have multiple copies of this vector happening:

```
 mat->deviceVector=thrust_vector_fill_range<dtype>(mat->deviceVector, 1, mat->size);
```

I suspect that `thrust_vector_fill_range`() does not take its parameter by reference, but rather by value. So, this is going to make a copy of the entire vector for the function parameter. Then, the returned vector will get copied again. True, the returned vector will get destroyed immediately afterwards, but your compiler is too old to support move semantics, so this will have to be done the old-fashioned way.

To summarize, if you don't want to make needless copies of your vector, write the code correctly, that doesn't do it. Do not instantiate a separate copy of the vector, just to copy it into the struct. `resize()` or `reserve()` and populate the struct's vector, and then always pass it by reference.

Comment: This answer contains very sound general advice. However a few details aren't going to work in this particular problem, because (although the OP didn't mention it) the deviceVector class in question is actually a container class which encapsulates memory on a GPU and there are some restrictions on what can or cannot be done with this particular class compared to `std::vector`